# L'utilisation du partitif dans la phrase « J'aurais trouvé du travail » ?

Tags: partitif

> Si j'étais rentré en France, j'aurais trouvé **du** travail.

Pourquoi on utilise le partitif et pas un article indéfini? Est-ce que la phrase « J'aurais trouvé un travail » est correcte quand même ? Signifie-t-elle la même chose ?

Answer (score 5):

Oui les deux phrases sont à peu près équivalentes.

Dans la première, *du travail* est au sens *d'activités rémunérées (qui rapportent de l'argent)* tandis que la deuxième est au sens de *un emploi* particulièrement.

Autrement dit, on peut nuancer les deux du fait que dans la première on aurait pu trouver **plusieurs** emplois tandis que dans la deuxième on aurait pu trouver **un** emploi.

En anglais la première donnerait :

> If I had returned in France, I would have found some work.

La deuxième :

> If I had returned in France, I would have found a job.

Answer (score 4):

"Du travail" is generic, "un travail" refers to a specific job.
Ex: "Beaucoup de gens cherchent du travail". "Many people are looking for work".
    "Marie a trouvé un travail temporaire de caissière". "Marie found a temporary job as a cashier".

Answer (score 1):

Les deux phrases veulent dire pratiquement la même chose, ce qui implique que les gens ne devraient pas normalement confondre les deux phrases si elles sont utilisées de manière alternative. Cependant, si nous analysons de manière plus approfondie les informations qui nous sont données:

> Si j'étais rentré en France, j'aurais trouvé du travail.

Dans la première phrase, la personne dit que si elle était rentrée en France, elle aurait trouvé quelques petits boulots çà et là. (Ou plutôt un travail quelconque)

> Si j'étais rentré en France, j'aurais trouvé un travail.

Dans la seconde, la personne dit qu'elle va se trouver un emploi en particulier.

J'espère que cela t'aide un peu plus !

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec ton interprétation de la première phrase. C'est vrai que « un travail » ne colle pas avec des petits boulots, mais par contre, « du travail » colle tout à fait avec un emploi à plein temps sur la durée.

Comment: @Gilles Serait-on d'accord pour dire que finalement «du travail» devrait plutôt signifier un emploi quelconque, sans égard à la volonté de trouver un emploi qui conviendrait mais plutôt dans l'optique de trouver un emploi à tout prix, tandis qu'«un travail» signifierait alors qu'il y a un objectif de trouver un emploi spécifique, donc davantage de recherche? Peut-être suis-je complètement dans le champ. Qu'en penses-tu?

Comment: Hmmm. Non, je ne perçois pas ça non plus. Je ne vois pas de différence entre « du travail » et « un travail » à part que *un* implique l'unicité (donc pas deux emplois à temps partiel ou une succession de petits boulots).

Comment: Devrais-je retirer ma réponse de la liste ?

Comment: Non, il n'y a pas de raison. Vu la proximité des deux phrases, on est dans le domaine du ressenti, et le fait que des francophones n'ont pas la même impression est en soi une information intéressante.

Comment: J'ai ajouté une petite précision sur le sens que je voulais donner à mon interprétation de la première phrase.

Comment: A mon sens (c'est une question d'opinion comme le dit @Gilles), la nuance entre les deux formulations est que, dans la première, on fait référence au marché du travail qui rend possible une embauche et que, dans la deuxième, on est plus focalisé sur les qualités de la personne qui lui permettent se trouver un travail.

Comment: Intéressant je n'avais pas pensé à trouver `du travail` comme dans le sens de : le marché `du travail`. Intéressant comme addition.